# Write a script so that a cell has specific text in it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I write a script so that a Google Spreadsheet cell has specific text in it?

I know how to in VB:

```
Range("A4").Value = "Amt. Refunded"
```

But not in Google Spreadsheets JavaScript.

Comment: When you say cell, do you mean element?  Are you asking about script that will be used in a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [Google Apps Script Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.getRange("A4").setValue("Amt_Refunded");
```